# How do I switch between the game screen and score screen without redrawing everything?

Tags: libgdx, rendering, menu

I'm working on a multiplayer game in Libgdx and  want to display the scores of say, the top 10 players on the map. The player should be able to checking the scores at any point during the game and return to the game screen (with themselves in the same location they were at earlier), much like pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> during a game of *Counter Strike* displays the scores.

Changing the screen to the score screen is simple enough using `setscreen`, but how can I return to the previous view without calling a `setscreen` on the game screen and rendering everything all over again?

Comment: There's probably no real way around that (note that I've never used libdgx so far). You'll typically have to redraw everything, unless you store the output in a render texture, but that wouldn't make any sense here IMO. Things like that are typically organized using a finite state machine, possibly in combination with a stack. Whatever is on top of your stack is updated/rendered. To go back to a previous screen, you just pop the top.

Comment: What is `setScreen`? Is that a libGDX function or your own function?

Comment: setScreen is a libgdx function used to change between screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then make something like:

```
enum gameState = { PLAYING = 0, MAINMENU = 1, SCOREBOARD = 2, ... }

if(Player.action = PLAYING)
{
    ... do stuff ...
}
else if(Player.action = MAINMENU)
{
    ... do stuff ...
}
else if(Player.action = SCOREBOARD)
{
    ... do stuff ...
}
```

And about the rendering. It's hard to get around that.

Comment: Rather than comparing the value of `Player.action` you're assigning it. Plus I'd use `switch()` rather than multiple instances of `if()` even if it's just for readability.

Comment: Well, you could do switch. But the point is. You could give the player an INT action.

I do it this way. And it works great.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create some table, whatever. that will be displayed on the current screen.

the values is the question important here. You have to call from where? got it?

if you saved the values on SQLite you can make a method that load the top scores.

you can read something about multiple input processors to alternate inputs when the user

click on score button (active scoreinputprocessor) and reactive gameinputprocessor when close score.

i did it just like this. i did got nice results.

**REFERENCE:**

Ok man, the files that you have to read to learn and use your creativity:

Multiple processors: [InputMultiplexer](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/24/LibGDX-Tutorial-5-Handling-Input-Touch-and-gestures.aspx#widgeteb854d9e-b569-4de6-ad92-112e7769a1f0)

Table: [Table Layout](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout)

**EXAMPLE**

[image: Example]

Comment: This doesn't seem to really address the question at all.

Comment: On the contrary, this is probably the most appropriate answer for what the OP wants, especially in libGDX. Using a scene2d-ui Table will allow an overlay on top of the current screen without having to perform a setScreen(). Hence, the state of the game, including all the elements can remain while the score overlay is painted over the screen. The use of the multiplexer will enable touches to be sent to the score overlay without affecting the game underneath. Upon closing the overlay, the game can be resumed as per normal by in registering the overlay as an input processor.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't think this answer explains, to the asker, what actually needs to be done in a useful and coherent fashion. Your explanation is much better -- perhaps you should post it as an answer or submit a clarifying edit.